# Get Country code from mobile number

Tags: leads, mobile

In my leads table, There is one column of mobile number example +971552400000. I want to show the country code +971 is separate column. how can i do this?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help), scroll through the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You should include an effort that led to the issue (the code, metadata, or design, in its current form) and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a formula field as mentioned in this [thread](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ia0rQAA)

For quick reference I am mentioning the formula used in above link:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Case_Phone__c), 'n/a',
CASE(LEFT(Case_Phone__c,4),
'+225', 'Ivory Coast',
'+351', 'Portugal',
'+353', 'Ireland',
'+380', 'Ukraine',
'+228', 'Togo',
'+223', 'Mali',
'+237', 'Cameroon',
'+216', 'Tunisia',
CASE(LEFT(Case_Phone__c,3),
'+33', 'France',
'+39', 'Italy',
'+48', 'Poland',
'+49', 'Germany',
'+32', 'Belgium',
'+34', 'Spain',
'+40', 'Romanai',
'+36', 'Hungary',
'Other'))
)
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks